# Any way to set default foreign key in JPA or Spring-data?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, foreign-keys, spring-data

Given the following JPA annotations on a `User` entity class, is there a way to set the default `Role`?

```
@Entity 
public class User {
    ...

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Role.class, optional = false)
    private Role role;
```

Right now I am setting the default in my initial Wildfly migration as follows:

```
create table users (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    name varchar(255), pwhash varchar(255),
    role_id bigint default 1 not null,              <- defuault FK ID set
    primary key (id));
alter table users
    add constraint FKtjpac0ubm4g9y5a5qi5ivebmw foreign key (role_id)
    references roles;
insert into roles (name) values ('USER');
```

However, that default is only visible in the SQL file. I would prefer to have it in JPA, too.

Or is this sort of functionality rather set in the repository/DAO?

---

Based on on of the answers I tried this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    ...

    public final static Role DEFAULT_ROLE = new Role();
    static {
       DEFAULT_ROLE.setId(1L);
       DEFAULT_ROLE.setName("USERS");
    }

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Role.class, optional = false)
    private Role role = DEFAULT_ROLE;
```

However, this throws a `ConstraintViolationException` on INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the exact SQL to create your database column using `@Column(columnDefinition="....")` including any default values.

In order to keep the Java representation consistent with that default, you can initialize the `role` field on construction, assuming `Role.defaultRole` is the `Role` you want to use as a default. Obviously, you have to take care that the default Role is properly attached to your session, i.e. you probably want to load it from the `Session` in the first place:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Role.class, optional = false)
private Role role = Role.defaultRole;
```

Comment: What is `Role.defaultRole`?

Comment: Just an assumed static field referencing the `Role` you want to use as a default.

Comment: I just tested this and you would need to have a reference to a mapped `Role`. I tried creating a static Role object that is not connected to the entity manager and an insert (save) of the user yielded a `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: I assume you already have a Role row with id 1 in the database? Is so you need to load that and use it. If you just create a new one JPA will try to insert that, which triggers unique key violations.

Comment: Of course you need a reference to a managed `Role`, how else can JPA make sure the `Role` entity still exists when you try to assign it to a `User`? If the set of `Roles` in your app is fixed, make `Roles` an enum, otherwise I think your requirement is not realistic.

Comment: Okay, I guess I would need to implement this behaviour in a manager/DAO/repository then I guess, since I don't want the entity to depend on the entity manager. Thanks, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also,

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID", columnDefinition = "int default 1")
private Integer role_id;
```

Comment: When using this, can I still get the `Role` object from a `User` by the `role` field like this: `user1.role`? Otherwise this would work against the whole idea of an ORM,

Comment: You can get the Role object by role_id from Role table. (Here role_id is id of Role object)

Comment: Why do you use an Integer attribute instead of a Role attribute?

Comment: I understand that, but the whole point of using JPA is for not having to access entity objects by IDs, but by automatically set up relations.